# How can I translate a curl call into java

Tags: java, curl

I have this curl call

```
 curl -d "variable1=text1&variable2=text2&variable3=text3" -d information='{"id":"1234567489", "token":"AAACSweqPLFPrf8F6r1sux2AZDZD"}' https://localhost:8080/token
```

And I'm trying to convert it into a Java call, but I don't know how to manage the 2 types of fields (url encoded and json)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out, just needed to URL-Encode the JSON part of the call and then I was able to make the call just with an entire url-encoded body using the regular Apache HTTP Client.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do URL/HTTP stuff in Java you will want to look into [Apache HTTP Client Library.](http://hc.apache.org)

If you are trying to parse JSON then you will want the [JSON libraries.](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net) 
Alternatively if you want get your hands dirty you can make use of java.net.URL and/or java.net.URLConnection:

```
URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");
BufferedReader reader = null;

try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));

for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
} finally {
if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
}
```

Also see [Oracle's simple tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) on the subject. It's however a bit verbose.

Swift